# Getting StaleElementReferenceError repeatedly

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am trying to automate an application with consist of nested iframes. My First approach was with watir-webdriver but it is taking way too long to fill each field and I've enter many. An example of an element in my page class is below:

```
in_iframe(:id => 'something') do |frame|
  in_iframe({:id => 'something'}, frame) do |frame|
   in_iframe({:id => 'something'}, frame) do |frame|
    in_iframe({:id => 'something'}, frame) do |frame|
     in_iframe({:id => 'something'}, frame) do |frame|
       text_field(:first_name, :id => 'something', :frame => frame)           
     end
    end
   end
  end
end
```

After trying out with watir-webdriver, I decided to go ahead with selenium-webdriver but i am getting StaleElementReferenceError repeatedly. I even kept a begin rescue retry block to avoid this but it keeps throwing the error.

All the elements are stored in page class and i am using populate_page_with method of page class to enter values.

> my_step.rb

```
When /^I (?:select|fill in) "(.*)" for (.+) (?:text field|drop down)$/ do |value, page_element|
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 30)
  wait.until { @current_page.send(page_element.gsub(" ","_").downcase + "_element").exists? }
  @current_page.enter_element_value(page_element, value)
end
```

> my_page.rb

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  in_iframe(:id => 'something') do |frame|
    in_iframe({:id => 'something'},frame) do |frame|
      text_field(:my_element, :id => 'something', :frame => frame)
    end
  end
end
```

> enter_element_value function

```
def enter_element_value(field, value)
  populate_page_with "#{field.downcase.gsub(' ','_')}".to_sym => value
end
```

I tried to enter the same drop down with selenium functions and i was able to

```
sleep 5
@browser.switch_to.frame('GFXLoanSelectorFrame')
@browser.find_element(:id => 'lsProcCombo').find_elements(:tag_name => 'option')[1].click
@browser.switch_to.default_content
```

And if I call my step to enter the same drop down again it throws the StaleElementReferenceError error. I am not sure what exactly is causing this. Also, Please let me know if I can follow any other approach to speed up the execution because with watir-webdriver it took around 10 minutes to fill only 2 screen which is like 20% of my target.

Answer (score 0):

default content I believe got back to the root page, you will need to navigate bath through to the parent frame from the beginning.

Consider a different recursive method.

Comment: my issue is with the page objects. I can't write a new line of code for each element.

Comment: I cannot help now but in a few weeks time I will have something that does not require page objects.

Answer (score 0):

staleelementexception is mostly caused when you loose the reference of the object after a action is performed and the state is changed. it may be due to ajax call or dom update. you can find different approaches discussed here
[How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium)

Comment: I tried the same approach with begin rescue retry block and it gives me the same error. The issue is coming with the page-object '_element' method. If i use page object method to click an element it works (eg. page.my_button) but if i try to get the element and then click on it, i get the above error (eg: page.my_button_element.click ). As i am guessing, page object is returning reference to the old element.

Comment: can your try one of the methods given here: https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5112655,  here is the reference post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-stale-element-reference-exception?rq=1

Comment: These solutions will work for me without any issues. Its the page object gem that is throwing the error.

Comment: There is already an issue logged for this https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/224