# Using selenium, I need to iterate over all iframes and their child iframes on the fly

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver

**I need to iterate over all iframes and their child iframes on the fly as I want to perform some action on all the `<img>` tags. I am using selenium.**

```
public class logic {

static WebDriver driver;
static List<WebElement> TotaliinnerFrames=null;

logic() 
{
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("aaaa.html");
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    logic log=new logic();
    find_parent_iFrame();
}

private static void find_parent_iFrame() 
{
    List<WebElement> TotaliFrames =  driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    System.out.println("TotaliFrames\t"+TotaliFrames.size());

    for(WebElement frame:TotaliFrames)
    {
        System.out.println("calling main frame==============================>\t");
        findLandingPage(frame);
    }

    if(TotaliFrames.size()>0)
    {
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
    else
    {
        List<WebElement> canvas = driver.findElements(By.tagName("canvas"));
        List<WebElement> img = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
        List<WebElement> anchor = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
        if(canvas.size()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("inside canvas");

            for(WebElement canvTemp : canvas)
            {
                callClick(canvTemp);
            }
        }

        if(img.size()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("inside img");
            for(WebElement imge : img)
            {
                callClick(imge);
            }
        }

        if (anchor.size()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("inside anchor");
            for(WebElement anchorc : anchor)
            {
                callClick(anchorc);
            }
        }

    }
}

private static void findLandingPage(WebElement frame) 
{
    driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

    List<WebElement> canvas = driver.findElements(By.tagName("canvas"));
    List<WebElement> img = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
    List<WebElement> anchor = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
    System.out.println("canvas\t"+canvas.size());
    System.out.println("img\t"+img.size());
    System.out.println("anchor\t"+anchor.size());

    if(canvas.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("inside canvas");

        for(WebElement canvTemp : canvas)
        {
            callClick(canvTemp);
        }
    }

    if(img.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("inside img");
        for(WebElement imge : img)
        {
            callClick(imge);
        }
    }

    if(anchor.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("inside anchor");
        for(WebElement anchorc : anchor)
        {
            callClick(anchorc);
        }
    }

    TotaliinnerFrames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    System.out.println("TotaliinnerFrames\t"+TotaliinnerFrames.size());
    int innerframesize=TotaliinnerFrames.size();
    if(innerframesize>0)
    {
        System.out.println("TotaliinnerFrames\t"+innerframesize);
        for(WebElement inframe:TotaliinnerFrames)
        {
            System.out.println("calling inner recursive\t");
            findLandingPage(inframe);
        }
        TotaliinnerFrames.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
}

private static void callClick(WebElement canvTemp) 
{
    try
    {
        canvTemp.click();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception unable to click");
    }
}
```

}

### **I need to Iterate over all iframe and its child iframe on the fly i want all tags and perform some action. using selenium.**

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes then what were the issues/error you faced?

Comment: I've updated the code am getting stale element exception please suggest me...

Comment: Please edit you question and put whatever you have tried with your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hold references to `WebElement`s across page loads (e.g. initiated by clicks), as they are only valid on their **own** page. They're not just any old Java object. You will get `StaleElementReferenceException` as you've seen.

Work page by page, not *across* multiple pages.

**Edit:** here's [an even better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244739/954442).