# Element not found in cache - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have List of URLs and I just wanted to open the URL on same browser session. To do that I have written the below code but it is throwing the error after opening the first URL i.e. second URL is not being opened.

```
findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-user-found']//p/a"));

for (WebElement webElement : findElements) 
{
    Thread.sleep(200);
    System.out.println(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
    driver.navigate().to(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
    Thread.sleep(200);
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
```

Please assist.

Comment: Here's another very good, clear answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16244739/954442

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to another page the DOM is changing and the `WebDriver` is loosing the elements it previously located. That causes the `StaleElementReferenceException`. I suggest you save the links as strings and use them.

```
List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-user-found']//p/a"));
List<String> hrefs = new List<String>();

for (WebElement webElement : findElements) 
{
    hrefs.add(webElement.getAttribute("href"));
}

for (String href : hrefs) 
{
    Thread.sleep(200);
    System.out.println(href);
    driver.navigate().to(href);
    Thread.sleep(200);
}
```