# Selenium WebDriver stale element because test is faster than UI when using Knockout.js

Tags: c#, knockout.js, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML page that is using Knockout.js to populate some list.

An item is added to the list when I click a button.

I write Selenium WebDriver test:

- I find the button, then click on it.
- Then I find the new element.
- Then I test the text of the new element.

I get a stale element exception.

If I wait after the click (paused in debugger, or adding a Thread.Sleep of about 500ms) the test passes.

How can I make sure the element I find isn't stale? Is there a property given to me by WebDriver I can test for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-stale-element-reference-exception?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define implicit wait to make sure the element exists before interacting with it

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

This will wait up two 10 seconds for the element to exists in the DOM

There might be additional JS changes, so you can use explicit wait with [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("id"), "text"));
// do something with the element
```

This will wait up two 10 seconds for the element to contain the text.

Comment: I actually do something of that manner and I still get the StaleElementException when I try to access the element's text if I don't wait. That's why it's so weird to me.

Comment: Is it possible knockout.js is changing the visibility/attachment of the elements it's adding several times while adding them?

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim Yes, it is. If I think the element is deleted from the DOM and than re-added to it. Try to use one of the text accepted conditions, for example `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("id"), "text"));`

Comment: I didn't really want to go there, as I don't think this is a robust solution (anyway, it feels wrong waiting for element's text), but unfortunately it seems this is the only way to go. Thanks.

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim The only other option I can think of is using `Thread.Sleep`. You need to decide wich one is the lesser evil.