# Looping through pages and getting StaleElementReferenceException in python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So I am looping through a bunch of webpages. And currently the webpages all have the same structure with a back button and a forwards button `(//span/a)[2]`. For some reason I can loop through the first page (and sometimes the second page). However I continue to get a `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Here is the related code:

```
for x in range(0,5):
    print 'page %d' %(x)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span/a)[2]"))
    )
    listItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='CourseCode']/a")
    for element in listItems:
        elementText = element.text
        print(elementText)
        writeFile.write(element.text + '\n')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span/a)[2]").click()
```

In particular here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "getList.py", line 21, in lookup
addListItems(driver, courseCodeFile)
File "getList.py", line 44, in addListItems
elementText = element.text
File "/home/francisco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 73, in text
return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
File "/home/francisco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/home/francisco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/francisco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
```

I've tried a bunch to no avail. The weird thing is, if not looping through I was able to get the function to work properly for two pages.

Of note prior to the RTE, it would print the text of the first 2-3 elements of `listItems` that were obtained in the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid `StaleElementReferenceExpection` by using [stalenessOf](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) `Expected Condition` in `WebDriverWait`.

---

[StaleElementReferenceExpection](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) occurs in two common cases:

1. The element has been deleted entirely.
2. The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

As you are using **common** locators across all the web pages, once you click on an element, selenium is still referencing to the locators in the previous page (`DOM is NOT yet updated, still referencing to the old web page)`

One simple solution is to add `time.sleep` at the end of the code, so that DOM will get updated, and the locators will be applied on DOM of the new web page.

```
for x in range(0,5):
    print 'page %d' %(x)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span/a)[2]"))
    )
    listItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='CourseCode']/a")
    for element in listItems:
        elementText = element.text
        print(elementText)
        writeFile.write(element.text + '\n')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span/a)[2]").click()
    import time
    time.sleep(0.5) //0.5 seconds
```

---

Another solution is to check for unique elements in each web page, which may not be possible in a `for loop` (possible if you use `if-else` & `indexing` etc.)

Comment: Just for some minor clarification. What is the point of the WebDriverWait then? As I understand this is to wait until that element is loaded. However in this case is it just still referencing the old DOM?

Comment: Yes, WebDriverWait is to wait until some condition is met, like Presence_Of_Element, Visibiliti_Of_Element etc. In your case, as locators are same, which are present in both the DOMs of both current and previous pages, giving exception. look for more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-how-to-resolve-stale-element-reference-exception & https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-. try with `stalenessOf` condition instead of sleep.

Comment: Used `staleness_of` and it worked perfectly. If you want to update your answer to mention to use the `staleness_of` on the `(//span/a)[2]` after the `click()`. I'd be happy to choose this as a solution.