# Stale element reference error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this fragment of my HTML code:

```
   <a class="button-color1 full" href="/AntecipacaoRecebiveis/AntecipacaoAutomatica">Simule e contrate</a>                        </div>
                        <div class="interntab clenitab" id="tabs-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9 taxa-mes" style="text-align:center">
                                    <span class="caption-value">a ser creditado em sua conta</span><br />
                                    <span class="value-simulator">R$ 0,00</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 a-ser-creditado" style="padding-top: 24px;">
                                    <span class="caption-value" style="font-size: 13px;line-height:6px">Taxa a.m.</span><br />
                                    <span class="value-simulator" style="font-size: 20px;line-height:8px">2,50%</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Then, I'm trying to automate my test by clicking on the `onclick="SetAdquirente('ADIQ')` (I had success on many other steps from the same website), but it is generating the following error:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
>   stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document 
>   (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.31.488763
>   (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

My code to find it is:

```
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id('tabs-2')
    action.move_to_element(elem)
    action.click()
    action.perform()
```

Why is this happening?
(I've tried to use others find_element statements, such as xpath, link text, etc and the same result raises)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you link the webpage?

Comment: @Mohamed unfortunately this is on development environment and has no  external access.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244739/677518

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver How to Resolve Stale Element Reference Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-how-to-resolve-stale-element-reference-exception)

Answer (score 0):

The StaleElementException occurs when the webelement in question is changed on the dom and the initial reference to that webelement is lost.

You can search for the webelement again

try this

```
try:
  elem = driver.find_element_by_id('tabs-2')
  action.move_to_element(elem)
  action.click()
  action.perform()
except StaleElementReferenceException:
 elem = driver.find_element_by_id('tabs-2')
 action.move_to_element(elem)
 action.click()
 action.perform()
```

Comment: Thank you, @michael-satish. But it doesn't solve my problem. It returns the same error.