# Selenium testing, Navigating pages

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working with selenium! I want to store the mobile names of a page in an Excel sheet, which I did with ease! 
Now my requirement is, I need to navigate to next page and store the mobile names of next page in same Excel sheet, I need to navigate to the last page and store the mobile names! When I'm trying, I'm getting stale reference exception! 
First I search a mobile in Amazon search box, I get mobile phones on the page, I get 5-6 pages! I need names of mobiles of all those 5-6 pages!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver How to Resolve Stale Element Reference Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-how-to-resolve-stale-element-reference-exception)