# Python Selenium StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I've seen solutions to this on other posts (mostly suggesting a longer waiting time), but have tried that and haven't had success.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LobbyistsPrep.py", line 126, in <module>
    the_download = get_file(year, report, download_dir)
  File "LobbyistsPrep.py", line 28, in get_file
    Year.select_by_visible_text(year_text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", lin
e 120, in select_by_visible_text
    self._setSelected(opt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", lin
e 212, in _setSelected
    option.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale elemen
t reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d902
3f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
def get_file(year_text, category, download_dir):
    # Store a list of files in the Downloads directory.
    # We will use this later to determine the filename of the the CSV we downloaded.
    downloads_before = os.listdir( download_dir )

    # Change the Year dropdown
    Year = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear'))
    Year.select_by_visible_text(year_text)
    time.sleep(30)

    # Change the Expenditure Type dropdown
    Type = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddExpType'))
    Type.select_by_visible_text(category)
    time.sleep(30)

    # Change the Report Month dropdown
    Month = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddMonth'))
    Month.select_by_visible_text('-- All Available --')
    time.sleep(30)

    # Click the Export to CSV button (downloads the CSV file)
    driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnExport').click()
    time.sleep(30)

    # Now that we have downloaded the file, lets check the Downloads directory again and compare.
    downloads_after = os.listdir( download_dir )
    downloads_change = set(downloads_after) - set(downloads_before)
    # If there is only one difference, then that file is the one we downloaded.
    if len(downloads_change) == 1:
        file_name = downloads_change.pop()
        file_path = download_dir + file_name
        return file_path
    # Otherwise, something went wrong: Either the number of files changed by MORE than one, or NOTHING was downloaded.
    else:
        return False

driver.get('http://mec.mo.gov/mec/Lobbying/Lob_ExpCSV.aspx')
time.sleep(30)

for report in reports_wanted:
    for year in years_wanted:
        the_download = get_file(year, report, download_dir)
        if the_download:
            if report == 'Group':
                print 'Downloaded ' + the_download + '. Adding to GROUP.  Report:\t' + year + '\t' + report
                group_files.append(the_download)
            else:
                print 'Downloaded ' + the_download + '. Adding to INDIV.  Report:\t' + year + '\t' + report
                files.append(the_download)
        else:
            print 'PROBLEM DOWNLOADING: \t' + year + '\t' + report
```

Our time.sleep used to be time.sleep(2) - I've tried changing it to 30, but that doesn't help, either.

I'm still pretty new to de-bugging scrapers, and this one wasn't built by me, so please be gentle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The element name seems auto generated. Are you sure that this name remains same always?

Comment: It looks like you are snagging the element, then the page is loading again and it's going `stale`, also your waits should be placed a few lines up, before this line`Year = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear'))`. There are better ways to deal with **dynamic load events**, such as waiting for an element to be present that loads last after the load event that causes your element to go stale.

Comment: @PixelEinstein - you mean the time.sleep should be moved? tried that, still get the same error. And I have seen similar feedback as "it looks like you are snagging the element, then the page is loading again and it's going stale" but I don't really know what that means/how to fix. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML of the page you are interacting with? Or the **URL**? I can then build in answer that relates directly to your usecase.

Comment: http://mec.mo.gov/mec/Lobbying/Lob_ExpCSV.aspx 

Meanwhile, I'm trying explicit wait (WebDriverWait) but now getting a Timeout Exception.

Comment: @PixelEinstein the URL was in the original code I posted; is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: @jayohday, yes that works, did not see it first go through. Thanks. If someone has not helped you and you are still struggling with this, I will leave a detailed answer once I'm off work.

Comment: @jayohday, also, please update to `chromedriver 2.36` or **above** [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), so we know you have a driver that supports your current version of chrome `build 65-`.

Comment: @PixelEinstein the update fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @jayohday, great! Glad it worked.

Comment: @jayohday, I will make a quick answer so people know that updating fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

***Turning comment that fixed issue into answer for others.***

What ended up fixing the above issue, was updating the **Chromedriver** to at least `2.36` since they are running on `Chrome build 65`, which is not supported by their current version of `Chromedriver 2.33`: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

By keeping these up to date, or on a **recommended pair**, you will run into less problems as described on the chromedriver download landing page.

---

If you are looking for help with `StaleElementReferenceException`

Here is the definition from the *wiki*:

> Thrown when a reference to an element is now “stale”.
>
> Stale means the element no longer appears on the DOM of the page.
>
> Possible causes of StaleElementReferenceException include, but not
>   limited to:
>
> You are no longer on the same page, or the page may have
>   refreshed since the element was located.
>
> The element may have been
>   removed and re-added to the screen, since it was located. Such as an
>   element being relocated. This can happen typically with a javascript
>   framework when values are updated and the node is rebuilt.
>
> Element may
>   have been inside an iframe or another context which was refreshed.

Please refer to these:

- [Selenium HQ page](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)
- [Wiki](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html?#selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException)
- Some really good [Answers from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-how-to-resolve-stale-element-reference-exception) on that question

---

Answer (score 0):

I only have a solution in java, but it works.

If the exception is thrown I catch it and retry:

```
boolean isElementFound = false;

while(!isElementFound){

  try{

     WebElement myElement = Driver.findElement(By.id("elementID"));
     isElementFound = true;   

  }catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
    //nothing!
  } 
}
```