# Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document when looping through pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to go through each products in my catalogue and print product image links. Following is my code.

```
product_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product-link")
for link in product_links:
    driver.get(link.get_attribute("href"))
    images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#gallery img")
    for image in images:
        print(image.get_attribute("src"))
    driver.back()
```

But I receiving the error `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`, I think this is happening because when we go back to catalogue page the page get loaded again and the element references in `product_links` became stale.

How we can avoid this issue? is there any better solution for this?

Comment: The simplest solution is to [refresh](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=refresh#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.refresh) the page to re-establish the dom objects

Comment: @G.Anderson - Still same issue

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244739/677518

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver How to Resolve Stale Element Reference Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-how-to-resolve-stale-element-reference-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, and here's how I solved it. Basically, you have to refresh the page and re-establish the list of links each time you return to the page.Of course, doing this you can't use a `for` loop, because your objects are stale each time.

Unfortunately I can't test this, as I don't have access to your actual URL, but this should be close

```
def get_prod_page(link):
    driver.get(link.get_attribute("href"))
    images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#gallery img")
    for image in images:
        print(image.get_attribute("src"))
    driver.back()

counter=0
link_count= len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product-link"))
while counter <= link_count:
    product_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product-link")[counter:]
    get_prod_page(product_links[0])
    counter+=1
    driver.refresh()
```