# How to print selected option from drowdown by using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng

just want to print the value of selected option after selecting the option from dropdown .

```
package Webbasics;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class ecommerce {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://live.demoguru99.com/index.php/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav\"]//li[1]/a")).click();
            
            Select sortBy=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[contains(@title,\"Sort By\")])[1]")));
            
            sortBy.selectByIndex(1);
            Select sortBy1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[contains(@title,\"Sort By\")])[1]")));
            WebElement selected=sortBy1.getFirstSelectedOption();
            
            System.out.println(selected.getText());
            
        }
}
```

I am getting proper result but i think its not the best way of writing select class two times so can you help me to write in a better way

Comment: Remove the declaration of `sortBy1` and use `WebElement selected=sortBy.getFirstSelectedOption();` Unless the setting of the index causes the element `sortBy` to become `stale`, in which case, your code is correct.

Comment: yes, it thrown stale element exception that's why I declared it with another object reference

Comment: Then your code is correct. You can't use the same object since it goes stale. You could however use the same variable, but set it's value again instead of using `sortBy1` -> `sortBy=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[contains(@title,\"Sort By\")])[1]")));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correct way with find element again after select the dropdown element, but after selected you should wait a while to make the element visible again.

See the following code:

```
Select sortBy = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//select[contains(@title,'Sort By')])[1]")));
sortBy.selectByIndex(1);

//wait here
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
sortBy = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//select[contains(@title,'Sort By')])[1]"))));
System.out.println(sortBy.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
```

But above I find again the element without creating a new variable name for the dropdown, still **`sortBy`**. Although with initialization the new variables should work too.

Don't forget to import the following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

[Reference discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-how-to-resolve-stale-element-reference-exception/16244739#16244739)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to wait element visible.
Secondly, use this code

```
Select select = new Select("Element");
WebElement tmp = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
```