Selenium Java - Script worked in Chrome devtools but not in Selenium JavascriptExecutor
Hello I'm trying to get this value from chrome console here but Selenium give me this error.
[main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.util.NamingUtils - Could not find parameter color
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: {"status":10,"value":"stale element not found in the current frame"}

This is my code:
public static JavascriptExecutor getJsExecutor() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) DriverManager.getDriver();
    return js;
}

getJsExecutor().executeScript(
                    "console.log('selected element: ', window.pfSelected.state);"
            );
     
Object response =  getJsExecutor().executeScript("return window.pfSelected.state;");

and the browser console actually logged out an object img
Is there any way to get pfSelected.state value from Selenium?

This is a common problem.
Maybe this answer could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16922300/13290239

Have you tried return pfSelected.state instead of return window.pfSelected.state? Can you share the URL?

@JeffC I tried but it returns the same error. This URL is from Shopify's app, you need to authorize

@İhsanTarık Sorry, can you make it clearer? I guess pfSelected.state is in a different iframe as the executeScript frame but I'm sure that I switched to the correct iframe before executing the script

Solution: It must be return window.pfSelected.state.id (string) instead of return window.pfSelected.state or window.pfSelected (object).
